# Assembly to pseudocode understanding

Tags: c, assembly, ida

I am trying to reverse a executable file (for learning RE), However i am stuck on a piece of pseudocode which has some things that I dont understand.Kindly help me to understand it so I can improve. Now I understand that there is an array which has number 32 till 2014th entry and from 2014th to 4095th entry there are the codes of character returned by fget.After that there is a little snippet of code which I am not able to  understand,the block is marked with **.

Code:

```
int sub_12A11A0()
{
  __int16 v1; // [sp+4h] [bp-24h]@13
  int v2; // [sp+8h] [bp-20h]@11
  int v3; // [sp+Ch] [bp-1Ch]@8
  signed int v4; // [sp+10h] [bp-18h]@13
  signed int l; // [sp+14h] [bp-14h]@16
  int v6; // [sp+18h] [bp-10h]@6
  int v7; // [sp+18h] [bp-10h]@13
  int v8; // [sp+18h] [bp-10h]@32
  signed int v9; // [sp+1Ch] [bp-Ch]@8
  signed int v10; // [sp+20h] [bp-8h]@8
  signed int i; // [sp+24h] [bp-4h]@1
  signed int j; // [sp+24h] [bp-4h]@4
  int k; // [sp+24h] [bp-4h]@13
  signed int m; // [sp+24h] [bp-4h]@27

  for ( i = 0; i < 2015; ++i )
    byte_12A3400[i] = 32;     
  for ( j = 2015; j < 4096; ++j )
  {
    v6 = fgetc(dword_12A33EC);
    if ( v6 == -1 )
      break;
    byte_12A3400[j] = v6;
    ++dword_12A3088;
  }
  v9 = j;
  v10 = 2015;
  v3 = 0;
  while ( v10 < v9 )
  {
    if ( v9 - v10 < 33 )
      v2 = v9 - v10;
    else
      v2 = 33;
    v1 = 0;
    v4 = 1;
    ****v7 = (unsigned __int8)byte_12A3400[v10];
    for ( k = v10 - 1; k >= v3; --k )
    {
      if ( (unsigned __int8)byte_12A3400[k] == v7 )
      {
        for ( l = 1; l < v2 && (unsigned __int8)*(&byte_12A3400[l] + k) == (unsigned __int8)*(&byte_12A3400[l] + v10); ++l )
          ;
        if ( l > v4 )
        {
          v1 = k;
          v4 = l;
        }
      }
    }****
    if ( v4 > 1 )
      sub_12A1120(v1 & 0x7FF, v4 - 2);
    else
      sub_12A10D0(v7);
    v10 += v4;
    v3 += v4;
    if ( v10 >= 4063 )
    {
      for ( m = 0; m < 2048; ++m )
        byte_12A3400[m] = byte_12A3C00[m];
      v9 -= 2048;
      v10 -= 2048;
      v3 -= 2048;
      while ( v9 < 4096 )
      {
        v8 = fgetc(dword_12A33EC);
        if ( v8 == -1 )
          break;
        byte_12A3400[v9++] = v8;
        ++dword_12A3088;
      }
    }
  }
  return sub_12A1090();
}
```

Comment: To me it is unclear what you are asking... where did you get the *pseudo code* from the asm code (which is not included in the question) and what do you mean by *help me to understand*? Understand on what level? Do you want to match some algorithm or do you need a line-by-line description of the code or what?

Comment: Hi I was tracing a program through assembly using IDA, when i reached this function I pressed tab which generated this pseduocode. I want to understand what does the lines marked with **** does as I am not able to understand it Most importantly this line,   for ( l = 1; l < v2 && (unsigned __int8)*(&byte_12A3400[l] + k) == (unsigned __int8)*(&byte_12A3400[l] + v10); ++l )

Comment: Just indexing some array, e.g. `foo[l][k] == foo[l][v10]`

Comment: But array is 1 dimensional

Comment: IIRC the pseudo-code from IDA may be incomplete, hiding some machine code which is not well understood by their heuristic trying to build up that pseudo code. So if you are trying to RE it completely just from pseudo, without verifying with actual machine code, you may run into weird things. At least I think I have seen some long time ago one question here on SO where it turned out few instructions were not visible in pseudo code and they were actually important to fully decipher that code functionality. The pseudo code is excellent tool to get some quick overview, but RE is manual labour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the important part is to understand

```
*(&byte_12A3400[l] + k)
```

This is equivalent to

```
byte_12A3400[l + k]
```